# Python - Pandas column merging/concatenating/joining

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have read the pandas tutorial and still need help.
I am new to using pandas so please bear with me.

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
#1
identifier1, identifier2,
1.1        , 1.2
2.3        , 4.4
```

and a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {'identifier1':'3.3', 'identifier2':'2.3', 'identifier3':'1.6'}
```

I want to update this csv with this dictionary such that columns with the same identifiers are appended to and a column is created for new identifiers.

```
#2
identifier1, identifier2, identifier3
1.1        , 1.2        , 1.6
2.3        , 4.4        , NaN
3.3        , 2.3        , NaN
```

This will be a repetitive update for this csv so in the future this process will look like:

```
dict = {'identifier2':'3.5', 'identifier4':'1.5'}
INSERT MERGE CODE HERE
#3
identifier1, identifier2, identifier3, identifier4
1.1        , 1.2        , 1.6        , 1.5
2.3        , 4.4        , NaN        , NaN
3.3        , 2.3        , NaN        , NaN
NaN        , 3.5        , NaN        , NaN
```

Append works, but not in the way I want, it gives me:

```
dict = {'identifier2':'3.5', 'identifier4':'1.5'}
new_df = pandas.Dataframe.from_dict(dict, orient='columns')
old_df.append(new_df, True)
#4
identifier1, identifier2, identifier3, identifier4
1.1        , 1.2        , 1.6        , NaN
2.3        , 4.4        , NaN        , NaN
3.3        , 2.3        , NaN        , NaN
NaN        , 3.5        , NaN        , 1.5
```

So when new columns are made I need the values to be in the top row. Like in #2 or #3

```
.merge(old_df, new_df, how='left')
```

gives me the old dataframe #2 with the old dataframe indexes concatenated.

```
identifier1, identifier2, identifier3, identifier1, identifier2, identifier3,
1.1        , 1.2        , 1.6
2.3        , 4.4        , NaN
3.3        , 2.3        , NaN
```

&

```
.merge(old_df, new_df, how='right') 
.merge(old_df, new_df, how='outer') 
.merge(old_df, new_df, how='inner')
```

either return my original dataframe or something not even close to what I was going for, like deleting all the rows under the indices.

Thank you for reading this long post, if you have any questions please leave them below and I will try to clarify anything ambiguous.

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dct, index=[0]), df], 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Created a dataframe from the given data and set the column names:

```
id1 = [1.1, 2.3, 3.3]
id2 = [1.2, 4.4, 2.3]
id3 = [1.6]
DF = pd.DataFrame([id1, id2, id3]).T

DF.columns = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

Defined a new dataframe for the new data to be added to the dataframe:

```
dict1 = {'id2':'3.5', 'id4':'1.5'}

New_DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dict1])
```

Identified the column names that are in both the dataframe:

```
Intersection = list(set(DF.columns).intersection(New_DF.columns))
```

Identified the column names that are only in the new dataframe:

```
Difference = list(set(New_DF.columns) - set(DF.columns))
```

Concatenated the columns in both the dataframes row-wise:

```
Final_DF = pd.concat([DF, New_DF[Intersection]], axis = 0, sort = False)
```

Reset index for the final dataframe:

```
Final_DF = Final_DF.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Concatenated the final dataframe and the columns that are only in the new dataframe column-wise:

```
Last_DF = pd.concat([Final_DF, New_DF[Difference]], axis = 1, sort = False)
```

Hope it helps.